# HTTP Verbs POST, PUT, DELETE: Where do these get "processed"

Tags: http

Before anyone says "duplicate" I have looked at other questions with similar titles and none answer my specific question, so please read on!

I am a complete web development novice but have started looking into very basic HTTP and HTML. My background is RPC/SOAP style services and desktop apps. The thing is I am really quite confused about HTTP itself at a fundamental level, in particular the POST, PUT and DELETE verbs.

I can understand that GET is used to request a page from a web server, but I don't understand what happens when you actually do any of the other three verb actions. If you are a hosting a web page on Apache or IIS and you have a web form with a submit button, presumably that will send a POST with the data you have filled out in the form...but what does the web server do with this? How does a web page even make use of PUT and DELETE? PUT what? DELETE what? Its not like you are calling some method on a service that then does an action against a database. I presume frameworks like ASP.NET come into play here, but in vanilla HTTP/HTML I just don't get how it fits together...

I am really totally missing something here...help appreciated!

Comment: "It depends". In the case of a web-application the Web-server will generally "hand off" control to the web-stack (e.g. ASP.NET). However, for various requests (unless intercepted) the web-server will be quite happy serving up "static content". There are often "mappings" and "handlers" involved.

Comment: Read this: http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put

Answer (score 0):

The questions you have are all answered in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), which outlines how servers should react to the [`POST`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5), [`PUT`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6), [`DELETE`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) methods. Each method (including the ones not mentioned here) has its own requirements and suggestions. If you look at the [raw text stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Http_request_telnet_ubuntu.png) of an HTTP request you'll notice that the first piece of data that gets sent over the wire is the HTTP verb. As far as how these methods are implemented on the server-side, that's completely dependent on the environment you're programming in. For example, if you were implementing your site in PHP you could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to determine how you should handle a request.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you are hosting your website (I'm assuming ASP .Net MVC here) on IIS your requests going to server side will mostly fall into only two categories of http verbs namely `GET` or `POST`. Have a look at below mentioned ASP .NET MVC code. At the controller level it is possible decorate our actions using any of the http verbs though:

[image]

Now let's first understand if we are using plain vanilla ASP .NET MVC framework (without any java script) then why every request falls into only two categories namely `GET` and `POST`.

Let's say I've a view (aka a web page) in my website which is responsible for registering new users visiting my website. You will see controller code as below:

```
namespace MvcTestApp.Controllers
{

        // GET: /Account/Register

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

You type the `http://localhost:9896/Account/Register/` url in your browser's address bar for loading the register view/web-page in your browser. That's like first request to the web page so your browser automatically defaults it to `HttpGet` verb as you are getting the web page for the first time. So in this case below method annotated with `[HttpGet]` verb gets called:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Now on the page I've a button which I click to initiate the registration process once I've provided all the details related to registration. If you look at the source of the web page then you see below html code for the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
```

Whenever you click on an HTML control of type `submit` its simple job is to post/submit the updated contents of the current page to the server. Any of the html controls including `input` html control which make server side request are capable of making only `HttpPost` verb requests through browser. Since it is an `httpPost` verb request to the server for exactly the same URL the below mentioned method which is decorated with `HttpPost` get called. ASP.Net run-time obtains this information from the client-request that it is actually an http POST request and hence decides to invoke the below method on the controller having `[HttpPost]` annotation:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    .....
    .....
}
```

Thus as long as you are not using any javascript on your view/web page you ultimately make either http get (first-time) request or http post (using html submit controls) request.

Out of CRUD operations, Create and Update/Modify operations are handled by the same method annotated with `[HttpPost]`.

HTTP put verb is used to create/replace a resource when two below conditions are satisfied:

1. The endpoint must be idempotent: so safe to redo the request over and over again.
2. The URI must be the address to the resource being updated.

You can read more about put vs post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest).

So if you business scenario on server side will be able to manage the constraints related to HTTP put verb then ASP.NET MVC has a provision for that. You can create an action inside the controller and decorate it with `[HttpPut]` and call it using using http put verb from browser.

Well, even if in some scenario where you happen to satisfy the criteria laid down by put verb then you will not be able to call it using HTTP submit button. You will have to resort to java script XMLHttpRequest (i.e. AJAX calls) to make put verb calls as shown below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Account/Register',
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Also, around the usage of http delete verb I've see people explicitly having an action defined on the MVC controller e.g. `void DeleteUser(int userId)` which is called using http POST verb.

So in summary, we can see that for http PUT, POST and DELETE verbs we just have actions/methods on server side which are called using http POST verb. I've not come across a scenario in usual business applications where I ever got thinking to decorate my MVC actions with `[HttpPut]` or `[HttpDelete]`.

Hope this helps you get some clarification.

Comment: what about web forms and verbs?